# check variable type inside Jinja2 in Flask

Tags: variables, types, flask, jinja2

The template file i created contains this:

```
{% if type({'a':1,'b':2}) is dict %}
    print "Oh Yes!!"
{% else %}
    print "Oh No!!!"
{% endif %}
```

---

Then Jinja2 responds by saying:

```
TemplateAssertionError: no test named 'dict'
```

---

I am completely new to Jinja2 and Flask

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You are looking for the [`mapping` test](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#mapping):

```
{% if {'a': 1, 'b': 2} is mapping %}
    "Oh Yes!"
{% else %}
    "Oh No!"
{% endif %}
```

Jinja is not Python though, so you don't have access to all the builtins (`type` and `print` do not exist, for example, unless you add them to [the context](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#the-context). In Flask, you do this with the [`context_processor` decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.context_processor)).

You don't actually need `print` at all. By default everything is output (unless you are in a child template that `extends` a parent, in which case you can do [interesting things like the NULL Master fallback](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/tricks/#null-master-fallback) because only blocks with names available in the master template are output).

Comment: mapping link: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#mapping

Answer (score 17):

In case you want to get a custom type you can access field name like in this example:

```
  {% if 'RelationField' in field.__class__.__name__ %}
      <div class="col-md-1">
      Manage object
      </div>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: This gives me an error, but at least it does print the type: `access to attribute '__class__' of 'timedelta' object is unsafe.`

Answer (score 14):

How about:

```
{% if {'a':1,'b':2} is mapping %}
    print "Oh Yes!!"
{% else %}
    print "Oh No!!!"
{% endif %}
```

see [List of Builtin Tests](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#builtin-tests) for reference.